# Looping mathRandom each row and column

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class kelasArray{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
    Scanner voker=new Scanner(System.in);
    int baris,kolom;
    int j=1;
    int k=1;


    System.out.print("Masukkan baris: ");
    baris= voker.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Masukkan kolom: ");
    kolom= voker.nextInt();

        // Total number of rows it will iterate
        for (j=1; j<=baris; j++) {
            System.out.print(+j+ "-"+k+ " ");
            System.out.print("  ");
            // total number of columns it will iterate
            for (k=1; k<=kolom; k++) {
              System.out.print(+j+ "-"+k+ " ");
              System.out.print("  ");
            }
            k=0;
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

So this is my code, I try to add a mathrandom each column and row.

The question is, where do I put my mathrandom? On first for? Or second for?

I already added this code

```
   int number=(int)(Math.random()*2);
             System.out.println(+number);
```

on the second for, but the output its not like what I want.

Anyone?

So here looks, like

[image: when I do not place mathRandom]

[image: when I place mathRandom]

Comment: `the output its not like what i want.` - you might want to start by telling us what it is that you want.

Comment: In addition to what _Thomas_ said (please state your current output and an example of the expected output), there is also an error here (could be a typo perhaps?): `System.out.println(+number);` You don't need the `+`, so it should be `System.out.println(number);`.

Comment: @Thomas i upload the pic, mathRandom just not place in each row&collomn

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yeah, i already remove + , and the code still work. i think we need add + to get value from some variable, like html do

Comment: what are you trying to do? do you want to fill each cell with random number?

Comment: @tupir where do you want your random number to be printed.

Comment: @SumeetSingh i want it printed each collomn and row. so it will looks like 
0-0    0-1
1         0
it print below each collom and row identity

Comment: @tupir got it now or still confused.

Comment: @SumeetSingh still confused where i must place it

Comment: Your images are the same and it's still not clear to me where the random numbers should be placed. Should each cell contain a different random number? Should all rows look the same, i.e. all cells in a certain column should contain the same random number? Should only the headers contain random numbers?

Comment: @Thomas each row and collum have a different random number, so we put mat.random on every loop ?

Comment: Probably yes but I still don't get it: should there be _one_ random number per column and row (i.e. the first row/column aka headers only) or should there be _multiple_ random numbers in each row and column, i.e. should _every cell_ have a different random number? In any case you'll want to create a new random number in each loop, the question only is: do you want to create a random number in each iteration or only the first?

Comment: Look into the `Random` class. It's a lot less clunky for getting ints than casting and `Math.random()`.